# How to reduce reserved memory allocated by Linux kernel during boot time

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am currently working on embedded linux os booting for which I am trying to fit linux boot within 32 MB system memory. While booting linux kernel I can see kernel is allocating almost 15 MB (15840K reserved as shown below) of memory as reserved,

```
Memory: 33312K/49152K available (5244K kernel code, 781K rwdata, 984K rodata, 
220K init, 268K bss, 15840K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

For 32MB memory, I see its too large, how can I reduce this? Can we control this memory limit using some kernel config option?

I saw one thread related to same here [reserved memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731988/linux-kernel-reserved-memory) on stack overflow. but it doesn't explain how to limit this memory during kernel boot itself.

As per solution given in this thread for me.

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
```

outputs to 768KB only. Which means this 15 Mb looks to free by kernel later?

Here is the snip of free command output in my case.
[image]
Note: kernel + rootfs consumes around 12MB space in my space.

Thanks, in advance.

I am expecting kernel should allocate reserved memory around 6 to 7MB during booting Linux kernel itself instead of 15 MB.

Comment: Have you read this code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L5919 ?

Comment: If you  are loading a compressed image you need enough room for it and the decompressed image, as well as stack and bss.

Comment: you can try to compile a custom kernel with less modules, features etc, which might help you with memory consumption. You can also try experimenting with different compression models to see if they make any difference.